# Implementing io.Writer interface in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to create a structure type which satisfies `io.Writer` interface via `Write` method:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    name []byte
}

func (p Person) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
    p.name = data
    return len(data), nil
}

func main() {
    b := []byte("Dave")
    person := Person{}
    fmt.Fprint(person, b)
    fmt.Printf("Person name: %s\n", person.name)
}
```

but instruction

```
fmt.Fprint(person, b)
```

doesn't work, `person.Name` remains empty slice. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two cents about value and pointer receivers. Function `Write` satisfying `io.Writer` can be defined both ways:

```
func (p Person) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
...
}
```

This way function operates on a copy of the `Person`, that's why you don't see changes after function finishes.

And:

```
func (p *Person) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
...
}
```

This way function works with a pointer to the original `Person`. That's why after the function end changes are visible.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the `Write` function to modify the receiver object,
you must make the receiver a pointer:

```
func (p *Person) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
    p.name = data
    return len(data), nil
}
```

The `fmt.Fprint` function uses the default format for its operands.
That's not what you want, you want to write the content of `b` as `"%s"`,
so you need to use `fmt.Fprintf` instead:

```
func main() {
    b := []byte("Dave")
    person := Person{}
    fmt.Fprintf(&person, "%s", b)
    fmt.Printf("Person name: %s\n", person.name)
}
```

See on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dYhddsHuWa).